# Scipy resample for downsampling, fourier method explanation

Tags: python, scipy, signals, signal-processing

I am seeking explanation of what "Fourier method" is that is described for resampling in documentation of resample() method. I want to downsample an array. I know what decimation is and how it works, I also know what fourier transform is. I cannot however find "scientific backup" so to say to the resample method in scipy. I saw this topic:

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/45446/pythons-tt-resample-vs-tt-resample-poly-vs-tt-decimate

I also searched across some books regarding digital signal processing. Am I missing something obvious? I looked in the implementation of resample and I know it performs fourier transform on signal and then takes half of samples needed from the beginning of transformed array and from the end. Then it inverses fourier transform coming back to time-domain. I cannot find scientific description of this method. In the link above, this was mentioned:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_interpolation#Relation_with_the_discrete_Fourier_transform

I don't understand how interpolation is connected with downsampling. Could anyone explain and/or link some resources? Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! We focus on specific programming / implementation questions here, see [What questions are on-topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), questions like yours may be closed as too broad. You already linked a question at dsp.SE, which may be a better place for a conceptual question.

Answer (score 0):

I have not looked into the code but I assume that what you have described is correct and the downsampling is implemented by inverse transform of truncated spectrum.

Lets separate this process into two steps. First zero the high frequencies related beams in the spectrum, which is low-passing of the signal. This step is required to verify no aliasing.

Second step is removing those beams. This step is the opposite process to zero-padding of the spectrum which is equivalent to upsampling. Therefore, removing the beams related to the high frequencies is equivalent to decimating in the time domain.